# Execute Node Tree from a bpy script outside animation nodes

Tags: python, animation-nodes

I want to iterate the Animation Nodes Node Trees in my current scene, and for each Node Tree, I want to execute it as if by clicking the Execute Node Tree button. When I click the button manually, I don't see any output in the Python console for this button, so I'm not sure where to begin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find AN node tree and `execute()`:

```
import bpy

anTreeNames = ["NodeTree", "NodeTree.001"]

for name in anTreeNames:
    tree = bpy.data.node_groups.get(name)
    if tree:
        tree.execute()
```